# How to uninstall nginx on CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos, nginx

I installed Nginx from src myself using [this guide](https://github.com/samayo/centopia/blob/master/09-Nginx-1.6.2.md) and now, I would like to get rid of it. But it seems there is nothing to do, aside from wiping out the src in `usr/local/src` I did `yum list installed | grep nginx` but nothing turns out. I doing `whereis nginx` gives me those directories.

```
nginx: /usr/sbin/nginx /etc/nginx /usr/share/nginx
```

So, my question is, if I want to completely wipe off nginx, would it be enough to remove those three directories?

Comment: That guide is pointless; you could just use the nginx official packages instead, or the EPEL packages. Not to mention it tries to use an old-style init script.

Comment: The guide is mine, and as I have [stated here](http://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/2mi4jb/new_to_bash_made_this_script_to_learn_the_basics/) it is only to get me started learning bash on the way. Besides, I don't see a big deal with building from source, as opposed to using outdated versions of nginx from yum. But the question is how do I clean nginx as it is now. I think this is a very good question, regardless of how I am installing it or how I tend to use it.

Comment: @samaYo Nginx.org provides latest packages in its repositories, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously yum doesn't know anything about software you installed without using it - how did you expect it to do so?

Sometimes a makefile will have an uninstall target you can use, try `make uninstall` and see if does anything.

Comment: This is a good point. Just what I thought. Too bad I removed the nginx folder already. What would you advise of removing nginx in the current situation? other than rebuilding centos from image?

Comment: You could try running the configure step again with the exact same parameters as before. That would generate a new makefile for you to run make uninstall

Answer (score 4):

You need to get into yum basics and particularly how to add a repository.

Nginx provides mainline and stable repositories for RHEL/CentOS (among others) with respective base URLs :

- mainline : `http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/OS/OSRELEASE/$basearch/`
- stable   : `http://nginx.org/packages/OS/OSRELEASE/$basearch/`

Then `yum install nginx` / `yum remove nginx` ...

Comment: 1st remove using 
```sudo yum remove nginx```

2nd find residual directories
```whereis nginx```

3rd finally remove the directories
```sudo rm -rf /usr/lib64/nginx /etc/nginx /usr/share/nginx```